How to print Arabic words in Flutter using Mobile Printer
I am attempting to print Arabic words in Flutter using a mobile Bluetooth printer (POZONE). However, the printer outputs blank pages. Here is the relevant code snippet:
code
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:esc_pos_utils_plus/esc_pos_utils_plus.dart';
import 'package:print_bluetooth_thermal/print_bluetooth_thermal.dart';
import 'package:charset_converter/charset_converter.dart';

Future<List<int>> generateTicket() async {
  List<int> bytes = [];
  CapabilityProfile profile = await CapabilityProfile.load();
  final generator = Generator(PaperSize.mm58, profile);
  const characterSet = 'CP1256';

  Uint8List arabicText = await CharsetConverter.encode(characterSet, "النجم السادس");
  bytes += generator.textEncoded(arabicText,
    styles: const PosStyles(
      height: PosTextSize.size2,
      width: PosTextSize.size2,
      align: PosAlign.center,
      bold: true,
    ));

  // bytes += generator.feed(2);
  return bytes;
}

Bluetooth Printer: POZONE
The printer outputs blank pages. Are there any necessary changes in printer settings such as the code page?
